# How can I get Web API autocomplete/IntelliSense in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions, web-frontend

I'm using VSCode for web development and I noticed that there is no JavaScript autocomplete/IntelliSense for browser-related types such as `Element` nor functions such as `document.querySelector()`. Is there an extension for this that anyone has found?

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "checkJs": true,
        "outDir": "./root/js",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "target": "ESNext"
    },
    "exclude": ["./root/**/*"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

I was starting to type out `document.querySelector()` and noticed halfway through that autocomplete wasn't triggering. I triggered it manually (`Ctrl-I`) and got no suggestions.

For clarification, I'm looking for something that will do this, but with frontend code:
[image: Screenshot of VSCode IntelliSense at work on a Discord.js project]

Tried searching for extensions in marketplace, on Google, in VSCode itself - to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that [the `lib` field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) (tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json) hasn't been set to include `"dom"`, which tells the TypeScript compiler (and VS Code's TypeScript support) to include types for web APIs like the DOM.

Fun fact: If you leave the `lib` field empty, TypeScript will assume certain things to be in it "by default". For more info on that, see [this answer I wrote to "How can I make vscode assume a node.js context, so that it doesn't assume `fetch` exists?"](/a/73367636/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out @user was right — I needed to add this to my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "lib": [
    "DOM"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's better if you explain why this solves the problem like I did in my answer post. Include links to documentation where appropriate.

Comment: Why do you need `"ESNext"`? How is that necessary to solve the problem presented in your question post? Or is that something that you already had before? Please clarify. It might feel like I'm picking on you, but I'm not. This is just the level of quality that is expected here on Stack Overflow. (see [answer]).